# DistributionList in a AddressEntry is a AddressEntry? - C#

Tags: c#, outlook, distribution-list

I am trying to extract members from a DistributionList. So, I wrote this,

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Outlook.AddressLists addrLists = null;

foreach(Outlook.AddressList addrList in addrLists)
{
if(addrList.Name == "XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX")
{
Outlook.AddressEntries = addrList.AddressEntries;

foreach(Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry in AddrEntries)
{
//do something
}
}
```

The problem is, in this AddressList - XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX, there are some AddressEntry items, and some distribution lists as well. When I do addrEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList(), it returns olOutlookContactAddressEntry for AddressEntry & olOutlookDistributionListAddressEntry for the distribution lists. But, the type of these distribution lists inside a AddressList is still being shown as AddressEntry. Should'nt they be AddressEntries?

Please help, I am seriously blocked.

What I am trying to do is get all the individual ExchangeUsers from a specified distribution list. Maybe someone can suggest me some other way of doing it, please :)

Phani

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which particular property returns an unexpected value? Why GetExchangeDistributionList? It will fails from the Distribution Lists created in your Contacts folder.

Comment: hi Dmitry, thanks for the reply. There are distribution lists inside another distribution list. A distribution list should be recognized as AddressList, but the inside one's are being typed as AddressEntry, which is not allowing me to go into it

Answer (score 3):

All address book items are represented by the AddressEntry object.

If you need to access the DL members, use the AddressEntry.Members collection - it will indeed return the AddressEntires obejct. It will be null if the item is not a DL.

Comment: hi Dmitry, I am using Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library, for Outlook 2010. I think AddressEntry.Members is implemented in Office 2013, but it is not present in the library I am using.

Office 2007 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176626(v=office.12).aspx
Office 2013 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry_members.aspx

Really appreciate your help :), can you tell me the way in 2010 Outlook

Comment: AddressEntry.Members property was present since Outlook 97. It might be hidden and thus not shown by Intellisense.